# Email sent to wrong account

Tags: python, django

Ive built an contact form which sends an email. I'm just having a bit of trouble in relation to the account its being sent to. I want the email to be sent from "servwishes@gmail.com" to the "Contact_Email".
Right now the email is going from "Contact_Email" to "servwishes@gmail.com".

my views.py looks like this:

```
def contact(request):
    Contact_Form = ContactForm
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = Contact_Form(data=request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            contact_name = request.POST.get('contact_name')
            contact_email = request.POST.get('contact_email')
            contact_content = request.POST.get('content')

            template = get_template('users/contact_form.txt')
            context = {
                'contact_name' : contact_name,
                'contact_email' : contact_email,
                'contact_content' : contact_content,
            }

            content = template.render(context)

            email = EmailMessage(
                "New contact form email",
                content,
                "Creative web" + '',
                ['servwishes@gmail.com'],
                headers = { 'Reply To': contact_email }
            )

            email.send()


    return render(request, 'users/contact.html', {'form':Contact_Form })
```

And my setting.py looks like:

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'servwishes@gmail.com' 
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = '*******'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
```

Comment: Gmail will replace the sender address with the authenticated users address.

Comment: Since you may be having trouble matching up your positional arguments, try using keyword arguments for everything.

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the order of your arguments and convert them from positional to keyword, you currently have:

```
        email = EmailMessage(
            subject="New contact form email",
            body=content,
            from_email="Creative web" + '',
            to=['servwishes@gmail.com'],
            headers = { 'Reply To': contact_email }
        )
```

I think there were a couple of issues here. I think you probably meant to do:

```
from_email='"Creative web" <servwishes@gmail.com>'
```

But since you didn't get that, it messed up the order of your positional arguments.

To should be `to=contact_email`

The other issue is I think you are misunderstanding the 'Reply To' header. That's who, when the recipient hits the reply button, the email will be sent back to. It is not who you are sending the email to.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback!
I am still having trouble making sense of it,

Are you suggesting something like this? 

email = EmailMessage(
                "New contact form email",
                content,
                from_email='"Creative web" <servwishes@gmail.com>',
                to=contact_email,
                headers = { 'Reply To': contact_email }
            )

I really appreciate your feedback!

Comment: Yes, let me know if that worked for you, except I think the 'Reply To' would probably be  `servwishes@gmail.com` so you don't really need it. You only need 'Reply To' if you write the email from one address but want replies to be sent back to a different one.

Comment: Thanks, if this answered your question, please mark it as the accepted answer. Best of luck with everything!